# nltk stopwords - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'words'

Tags: python, error-handling, nlp, nltk, stop-words

This is my import:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

And this is my code:

```
def stopwords(text):
"""a function for removing the stopword"""
sw = stopwords.words('english')
# removing the stop words and lowercasing the selected words
text = [word.lower() for word in text.split() if word.lower() not in sw]
# joining the list of words with space separator
return " ".join(text)
```

Applying:

```
df['col_text'] = df['col_text'].apply(stopwords)
```

I got this error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'words'

Someone can help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello the problem is that you've named your function like the nltk.corpus module. You should find an other name for your function and it'll work I think.